# How do I create a sub arrary in awk?

Tags: awk, arrays

Given a list like:

```
Dog bone
Cat catnip
Human ipad
Dog collar
Dog collar
Cat collar
Human car
Human laptop
Cat catnip
Human ipad
```

How can I get results like this, using awk:

```
Dog bone 1
Dog collar 2
Cat catnip 2
Cat collar 1
Human car 1
Human laptop 1
Human ipad 2
```

Do I need a sub array?  It seems to me like a need an array of "owners" which is populated by arrays of "things."

I'd like to use awk to do this, as this is a subscript of another program in awk, and for now, I'd rather not create a separate program.

By the way, I can already do it using sort and grep -c, and a few other pipes, but I really won't be able to do that on gigantic data files, as it would be too slow.  Awk is generally much faster for this kind of thing, I'm told.

```
 Thanks, 
 Kevin
```

EDIT:  Be aware, that the columns are actually not next to eachother like this, in the real file, they are more like column $8 and $11.  I say this because I suppose if they were next to eachother I could incorporate an awk regex ~/Dog\ Collar/ or something.  But I won't have that option.  -thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk does not have multi-dimensional arrays, but you can manage by constructing 2D-ish array keys:

```
awk '{count[$1 " " $2]++} END {for (key in count) print key, count[key]}' | sort
```

which, from your input, outputs

```
Cat catnip 2
Cat collar 1
Dog bone 1
Dog collar 2
Human car 1
Human ipad 2
Human laptop 1
```

Here, I use a space to separate the key values. If your data contains spaces, you can use some other character that does not appear in your input. I typically use `array[$a FS $b]` when I have a specific field separator, since that's guaranteed not to appear in the field values.

Comment: Hell yes.  I can't believe how simple that is.  For some reason, I thought I had to do something tricky to put two indices for an array...  Thanks buddy

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the additional comment as well.  With the actual file I'm sorting, which is more complex, yet consistent, I should be able to find a suitable FS delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Awk has some support for [multi-dimensional arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multi_002ddimensional), but it's really just cleverly concatenating keys to form a sort of compound key.

I'd recommend [learning Perl](http://learn.perl.org/), which will be fairly familiar to you if you like awk, but Perl supports true [Lists of Lists](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).  In general, Perl will take you much further than awk.

---

Re your comment:

I'm not trying to be superior.  I understand you asked how to accomplish a task with a specific tool, awk.  I did give a link to the documentation for simulating multi-dimensional arrays in awk.  But awk doesn't do that task well, and it was effectively replaced by Perl nearly 20 years ago.

If you ask how to cross a lake on a bicycle, and I tell you it'll be easier in a boat, I don't think that's unreasonable.  If I tell you it'll be easier to first build a bridge, or first invent a Star Trek transporter, then that would be unreasonable.

Comment: +1 for perl - even awk would require multi-line ( structured) programming to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, I understand this type of response, but it's not really an answer.  I don't reply in the windows related questions, "You should reformat and install a real OS , like Linux, problem solved."  So this shouldn't be acceptable either.